# Interupt signal when running interactive tty

Tags: bash

I have bash script like this :

```bash
trap "exit" INT

read -p "your text : " opsi

echo $opsi
```

My expectation when im submit CTRL+C on `read` input, it will trigger command `exit` like this:

```bash
user@host:~$ ./script
your text :^C

<exit/close/logout user session>
```

Is that possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to catch when the user hits `Ctrl-C` then you need to use the `SIGINT` signal.

`trap exit SIGINT`

This will execute the `exit` command (which, hopefully, you've defined somewhere else in your script) when the user hits Ctrl-C.

Also, avoid using `exit` as your command name as it's easy to catch a conflict with the built-in `exit` command to define the exit status of your script.

```
➜  ~ cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash

function script_exit()
{
    let ctrlc_count++
    echo
    if [[ $ctrlc_count == 1 ]]; then
        echo "Once more and I quit."
    else
        echo "That's it.  I quit."
        exit 1
    fi
}

trap script_exit SIGINT

read -p "your text: " opsi

echo $opsi
```

```
➜  ~ bash test.sh
your text: ^C
Once more and I quit.
^C
That's it.  I quit.
```

Comment: Im already find the solution, and its same with yours. Thank you, appreciate it !